# Can an array be used within the LinEst function in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba

Basically, rather that selecting a range from cells I have stored values in an array through the use of a loop. What I would ideally like to do is use these arrays as the known x's and y's in the LinEst function.

The purpose of this is unimportant as what I am trying to do is only part of the code I have already written. However, the Do loops (well at least the 2nd) do need to be there as the code I am attempting to apply this to requires them in order to function.

Below is a simple example of code I am trying to write.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Counter As Long
Dim Counter_1 As Long

Dim x As Single
Dim y As Single
Dim i As Single
Dim m As Single

Dim myArray_1() As Single
Dim myArray_2() As Single

ReDim myArray_1(i)
ReDim myArray_2(i)

Counter = 2
Counter_1 = 2

i = 0

Cells(1, 4) = "m"

x = Cells(Counter, 1)
y = Cells(Counter, 2)

Do

Do Until x = 0

myArray_1(i) = x
myArray_2(i) = y

Cells(Counter, 6) = myArray_1(i)
Cells(Counter, 7) = myArray_2(i)


i = i + 1

Counter = Counter + 1

x = Cells(Counter, 1)
y = Cells(Counter, 2)

ReDim Preserve myArray_1(i)
ReDim Preserve myArray_2(i)

Loop

m = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(myArray_2, myArray_1)

Cells(Counter_1, 4) = m

Loop

End Sub
```

So basically I want the LinEst function to use each array as known y's and known x's. Depending on what I change I get different errors, such as "type mismatch", or "unable to get the LinEst property of the worksheetfunction class". Either way I have so far had no luck in getting this to work and it always errors. From the LinEst function all I want is the gradient 'm'.

The only reason things have been put into cells is to make sure that the code is doing what I ask of it.

From what I can tell looking around the internet it is possible to use an array within the LinEst function, however the examples are usually drastically different to what I am trying to do.

If anyone can help at all I would be most greatful. Thank you in advance. Any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done. The code snippet below should help get you started:

```
    Dim x() As Variant
    ReDim x(1 To 3)
    x(1) = 1
    x(2) = 2
    x(3) = 3

    Dim y() As Variant
    ReDim y(1 To 3)
    y(1) = 4
    y(2) = 5
    y(3) = 6

    Dim z() As Variant
    z = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(x, y)
```

The function returns a `Variant` which "boxes" an array of `Variant` (which will be either one- or two-dimensional). The other two parameters (not shown above) are either True or False. The function is otherwise detailed in the Excel Help.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this with the below code. Hope it helps.

```
Sub RunLinEst()
    Dim vectorX() As Double
    Dim vectorY() As Double
    Dim theLeastSquareCoef


    'you need to define matrix otherwise it doesn't work
    ReDim vectorX(0 To 4, 0 To 0)
    ReDim vectorY(0 To 4, 0 To 0)

    vectorX(0, 0) = 0
    vectorX(1, 0) = 1
    vectorX(2, 0) = 2
    vectorX(3, 0) = 3
    vectorX(4, 0) = 4

    vectorY(0, 0) = 0
    vectorY(1, 0) = 1
    vectorY(2, 0) = 4
    vectorY(3, 0) = 9
    vectorY(4, 0) = 16


    theLeastSquareCoef = Application.LinEst(vectorY, Application.Power(vectorX, Array(1, 2))) 

    Range("F4").Value = Application.Index(theLeastSquareCoef, 1)
    Range("F5").Value = Application.Index(theLeastSquareCoef, 2)
    Range("F6").Value = Application.Index(theLeastSquareCoef, 3)


End Sub
```

Comment: Very helpful! You can also access each coefficient directly, since LinEst returns an array, i.e. theLeastSquareCoef(1), theLeastSquareCoef(2), etc.

Answer (score 0):

With this method one can also add another X-vector and get the results as follows:

```
vectorX(0, 1) = 8
vectorX(1, 1) = 5
vectorX(2, 1) = 7
vectorX(3, 1) = 1
vectorX(4, 1) = 3

theLeastSquareCoef = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(vectorY, vectorX, True, True)

MsgBox "if Y = a.X1 + b.X2 + c, then:" & vbNewLine & _
       "a = " & theLeastSquareCoef(1, 2) & vbNewLine & _
       "b = " & theLeastSquareCoef(1, 1) & vbNewLine & _
       "c = " & theLeastSquareCoef(1, 3)
```

Take note of the order of the results:

```
a = ...Coef(1, 2)
b = ...Coef(1, 1)
c = ...Coef(1, 3)
```

First 2, then 1, then 3