# Polynomial regression with array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, linear-regression

It appears that I'm not the only one to struggle with this, but I can't find an good answer, so I try my chance here!

I would like to find a 3rd degree polynomial line of best fit, given two sets of data stored in arrays. Basically, it looks like that

```
Dim X(0 to 9) as Integer
Dim Y(0 to 9) as Integer
for k = 0 to 9
   X(k) = 'something
   Y(k) = 'something else
Next
```

So far I've worked out how to  solve my issue with a 1st degree polynomial Y = aX + b :

```
a = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(Y, X, True, False)(1)
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(Y, X, True, False)(2)
```

I also found that if my values X and Y are written into a Sheet, I can find a higher polynomial with this :

```
 'x-axis values are entered in X column, y-values in Y column
 Z = Application.Evaluate("=linest(Y1:Y10,X1:X10^{1,2,3})")
 'The answer is in Z such that Y = Z(1)*Y^3+Z(2)*Y^2+Z(3)*Y+Z(4)
```

Assuming my arrays are already sorted, how can I use `linest` with arrays and not values entered into cells?

Comment: `LinEst` finds a line of best fit (i.e. regression) which is **NOT** interpolation. Are you sure you want interpolation or is regression what you are actually after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an array be used within the LinEst function in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267540/can-an-array-be-used-within-the-linest-function-in-vba)

Comment: You're right, I'm looking for regression. LinEst seems to do the trick pretty well. Unfortunately, I do not really understand what type of variable is `{1,2,3}`. I just copy-paste it from the Internet

Comment: @MarkBalhoff I've already seen this thread, but I don't understant how to apply it to my case (a 3rd degree polinomyal regression)

thanks for your help

Comment: `{1,2,3}` is an array if you want to use the array in a cell function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the OLS best fit coefficients (i.e. linear regression) and not interpolation, then you can do it like this for a second order polynomial:

```
Sub test()

    Dim X(0 To 9, 0 To 1) As Integer
    Dim Y(0 To 9, 0 To 0) As Integer


    i = 0
    For n = 0 To 9
       X(n, 0) = i
       X(n, 1) = i * i
       Y(n, 0) = i * i + 3 * i - 7
       i = i + 1
    Next

    B = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(Y, X)
    B2 = B(1)
    B1 = B(2)
    B0 = B(3)

End Sub
```

This correctly returns `-7` for `B0`, `3` for `B1` and `1` for `B2`. This is pretty much the same as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137957/1011724

You can make it more general, say a `k`-order polynomial like this:

```
Function f(X) As Integer ' This function is replaced by your data
    f = -2 * WorksheetFunction.Power(X, 3) + 3 * X - 7
End Function

Sub test2()

    Order = 3

    ReDim X(0 To 9, 0 To Order - 1)
    Dim Y(0 To 9, 0 To 0) As Integer

    'Note i is only to generate dummy data
    i = 1
    For n = 0 To 9 'Replace 9 with the length of your data
       X(n, 0) = i 'This line is replaced by your actual data
       ' Create the higher order features:
       For k = 1 To Order
           X(n, k-1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(i, k)
       Next
       Y(n, 0) = f(i) 'This line is replaced by your actual data
       i = i + 1
    Next

    B = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(Y, X)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this method only works for a linear regression, not a 3rd (or higher) degree ponynomial.
Or maybe I don't understand something in your code

Comment: I think I find out what was missing in my code. You define your array with `0 to 0`, which make it works ! But I'd like to understand what it means. What's the difference between `X(1 to 10)` and `X(1 to 10, 0 To 0)` please?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your edited post make everything clear as crystal !

Answer (score 1):

I've found another way to work with polynomial regression with arrays. The code is in this link. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression. Because the code in the website was not working due to incorrect array, I made a minor correction. It works now.

```
Function polynomial_regression(y As Variant, x As Variant, degree As Integer) As Variant
    Dim a() As Double
    ReDim a(1 To UBound(x), 1 To degree)
    For i = 1 To UBound(x)
        For j = 1 To degree
            a(i, j) = x(i) ^ j
        Next j
    Next i
    polynomial_regression = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(y), a, True, True)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a function to the above to use range variables as inputs to work as an equivalent to the Excel function linest()

```
Public Function RangeToArray(ByRef myRange As Variant) As Variant

    Dim individualCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ReDim myArray(1 To myRange.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each individualCell In myRange
        myArray(i) = individualCell.Value     
        i = i + 1
    Next
    RangeToArray = myArray
    
End Function

Function PolyFit(yRange As Variant, xRange As Variant, degree As Integer) As Variant
    Dim xAry() As Variant
    Dim yAry() As Variant
    Dim a() As Double
    
    xAry() = RangeToArray(xRange)
    yAry() = RangeToArray(yRange)
    
    ReDim a(1 To (UBound(xAry)), 1 To (degree))
    For i = 1 To (UBound(xAry))
        For j = 1 To (degree)
            a(i, j) = xAry(i) ^ (j)
        Next j
    Next i
    PolyFit = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(yAry), a, True, False)
    
End Function
```